# Getting an error message when trying to create an account or login

Tags: customer, email-templates, fatal-error

We are getting the error message you see below. This happens when trying to login or create a new account. Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setMessageBody() on a non-object in 
/home/skeleton/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 411
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an error with `$emailQueue` (Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)

This is a feature added since some 1.9 version

Do you have any modules involving email sending management, such as Mailchimp or SMTPPro?

If so, you should upgrade them to last version (to get support of queue feature) or disable them

If not, it seems incoherent to get an error if code has passed the `instanceof` & `$this->hasQueue` validation...

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
    $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
    ...
```